# C# .NET Core 3.1 Serilog usage in BackgroundService

Tags: serilog, background-service, ilogger

Following a tutorial on how to use Serilog I read the settings from an appsettings.json file - and all below works well, when things are simple:

Main program (in simple MVP version):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
//Read Configuration from appSettings    
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
//Initialize Logger    
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config).CreateLogger();

try
{
    Log.Information("Starting up the service");
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
....
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .UseSerilog();
```

Then the class with the BackgroundService:

```
....
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;//and not Serilog!!

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
   ....


    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

---------------------SIMPLE THINGS FOR ME ENDS HERE :-) ----------------------------------

Now, I want to build it up to a "real" program from this first MVP - placing function in seperate classes according to SOLID principles.For instance my first class is a ConfigurationCollector collecting all relevant paramters from the appsettings.json file that I place in a seperat class. The class works and does it jobs - but I want logging to work - and I try to use the allready configured Serilog logger used accross class (just as I did with ILogger, so that the Worker object creates a new ConfigurationCollector class like

```
public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configCollector = new ConfigCollector(logger);
    }
```

I know that logger is now a type of

```
ILogger<ConfigCollector>
```

which is not

```
ILogger<Worker>
```

But how do I inject the original Serilog from the initiation of the service into each class used, such that the objects are shown properly in the logs?

```
    public class ConfigCollector
    {
       private readonly ILogger<ConfigCollector> _logger;     
       ....
    public ConfigCollector(ILogger<ConfigCollector> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 Background service

```
.UseSerilog((builder, loggerConfig) =>
        loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration))
.Build();
```